# Knockout.js: View-Model function returns code?

Tags: design-patterns, knockout.js, viewmodel, revealing-module-pattern

Thanks to the [great Tutorial from John Papa](http://johnpapa.net).
I tried my best to implement the Revealing Module Pattern for my ViewModel using knockout.js

It is a very simple example:

- There are 2 Customer objects.
- Add the ID from both Objects and return it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasDeutsch/EHYfT/

Somehow I get not the value returned - but the code that is executed ?
I expected to see the result "3" on the screen :)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding two observables together.  Observables are functions.  Make sure you use the () form to get the actual value, like this:

```
addId = ko.computed(function () {
    return customer1.Id() + customer2.Id();
}),
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch. That explains it